# How to read value from a dropdown list using geb

Tags: browser, groovy, automation, webdriver, geb

I have the following list on a page :
    `SWM-product-priority-19900296 -`
    `<option value="">Select Priority</option>`
    `<option value="1">Low</option>`
    `<option value="2">Medium</option>`
    `<option value="3">High</option>`

I need to read the text value of the user selected or default option using geb and groovy. My code is as follows :

```
prioritySelectList(wait:true,required:false) {$("select#SWM-product-priority-19900296")}  `    
    prioritySelectedValue{prioritySelectList.find("option",value:prioritySelectList.value()).text()}`
```

When I print the value of prioritySelectedValue I get a null value. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work

Try

```
    prioritySelectList(...) { $("select#SWM...") }     
    prioritySelectedValue{prioritySelectList.find("option[value=\"${prioritySelectList.value()}\"]").text()}`
```

Comment: I tired this in similar circumstances and it works. Fiddle with JQuery on the screen and test the selectors try it yourself should work.